# How to add a legend for raster (GRID) layers in ESRI JS app

Tags: arcgis-9.3, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a grid in an MXD that I am publishing using ArcGIS Server 9.3.1.

In the TOC I have made a legend with labels against each of my 5 classifications.  I was expecting this to appear in my JS web app - but they never render.  Does anyone know how to make a raster legend to work with the ESRI JS API.

The code I am using is direct from the example pages - and it shows a legend for the basemap so I know the code is working to a certain extent:

```
//add the legend
        dojo.connect(map,'onLayersAddResult',function(results){
          var layerInfo = dojo.map(results, function(layer,index){
            return {layer:layer.layer,title:layer.layer.name};
          });
          if(layerInfo.length > 0){
            var legendDijit = new esri.dijit.Legend({
              map:map,
              layerInfos:layerInfo
            },"legendDiv");
            legendDijit.startup();
          }
        });
```

UPDATE - Begining to think that this is only available at v10.x.....

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I can confirm you need ArcGIS Server 10 for this to work.